# Manifest merger failed and cannot build the app

Tags: java, android, react-native, onesignal, android-push-notification

I am building an app using react native(detached) and after I installed onesignal library using npm install I can no longer build my app on Android Studio.

The following is the error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>     is also present at [com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).  Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Changes I made in react-native-onesignal build.gradle I changed buildtoolsversion to 26.02 as it was 23.0.1 smth...
Here is how it looks react-native-onesignal currently:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 23)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '26.0.2')

    defaultConfig {
        // Do NOT change these values here, set them in your android/app/build.gradle instead
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: '', onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE']
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"

    compile('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3') {
        // Exclude com.android.support(Android Support library) as the version range starts at 26.0.0
        //    This is due to compileSdkVersion defaulting to 23 which cant' be lower than the support library version
        //    And the fact that the default root project is missing the Google Maven repo required to pull down 26.0.0+
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        // Keeping com.google.android.gms(Google Play services library) as this version range starts at 10.2.1
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and my app build.gradle looks as:

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  flavorDimensions "default"
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.ferrometal'
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
  }
  productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
      // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
      // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
      // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    devRemoteKernel {
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    dev19 {
      // For debugging / development on older SDK versions. Increases build
      // time so use 'dev' if not running on older SDKs.
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
    prod {
      // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      zipAlignEnabled true
    }
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**"
  }
}

// Don't use modern jsc-android since it still has some critical bugs that
// crash applications when the string for the JS bundle is loaded and when
// locale-specific date functions are called.
// configurations.all {
//   resolutionStrategy {
//     force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
//   }
// }


task exponentPrebuildStep(type: Exec) {
  workingDir '../'
  if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '.\\detach-scripts\\prepare-detached-build.bat'
  } else {
    commandLine './detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'
  }
}
preBuild.dependsOn exponentPrebuildStep


dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  // Our dependencies
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'

  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
  compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'

  compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
  compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
  compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
  compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
  compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1'
  compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

  // Testing
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'



  compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:26.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }


}

// This has to be down here for some reason
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ANdroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  package="host.exp.exponent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <permission
    android:name="com.ferrometal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

  <!-- These are required permissions to make the app run -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.ferrometal.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <!-- ADD PERMISSIONS HERE -->
  <!-- BEGIN OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

  <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

  <!-- ADD TEST PERMISSIONS HERE -->

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true">

    <activity
      android:name=".LauncherActivity"
      android:exported="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTop"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="expac59f8b2959f4de3afc2b84696f00c3d"/>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".experience.ExperienceActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Light"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Splash"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".experience.ShellAppActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Splash"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <!-- ADD SHELL INTENT FILTERS HERE -->
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".experience.HomeActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Light">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <!-- ADD DEV SETTINGS HERE -->
    <activity android:name="abi26_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="abi25_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="abi24_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="abi23_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="abi22_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="abi21_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="abi20_0_0.com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>

    <activity
      android:name=".ExponentDevActivity"
      android:exported="true"
      android:label="@string/dev_activity_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Dark"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".oauth.OAuthWebViewActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Light">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
        tools:node="replace">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.ferrometal" android:path="oauthredirect"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".oauth.OAuthResultActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".chrometabs.ChromeTabsManagerActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".experience.ErrorActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Dark"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name=".experience.InfoActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Light">
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
      tools:replace="android:theme" />

    <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <service
      android:name=".ExponentIntentService"
      android:exported="false" />

    <!-- Analytics -->
    <receiver
      android:name="host.exp.exponent.referrer.InstallReferrerReceiver"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
    This crashes: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=667
    TODO: turn it back on when it's fixed
    <service
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false" />-->

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false"/>

    <!-- GCM -->
    <receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

        <category android:name="com.ferrometal"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
      android:name=".gcm.ExponentGcmListenerService"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
      android:name=".gcm.ExponentInstanceIDListenerService"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
      android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
      android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <!-- ImagePicker native module -->
    <activity
      android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    </activity>


    <!-- ADD FABRIC CONFIG HERE -->
    <!-- BEGIN FABRIC CONFIG -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
      android:value="a25fafe9f9edee11a9882b32e0cd7a26df6e2c42"/>
    <!-- END FABRIC CONFIG -->

    <!-- ADD GOOGLE MAPS CONFIG HERE -->
    <!-- BEGIN GOOGLE MAPS CONFIG -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyCPyKmt6in3JwAsogYikNNjor8qgU9stRQ"/>
    <!-- END GOOGLE MAPS CONFIG -->

    <!-- ADD BRANCH CONFIG HERE -->

    <!-- The Facebook SDK runs FacebookInitProvider on startup and crashes if there isn't an ID here -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb0"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Copy this `tools:replace="android:value"` and paste it in manifest in line on which your error redirects you and try again.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani line 26 on my manifest is empy, looks like some other manifest is needed to be changed...

Comment: No, other manifest doesn't need any change. I wrote line no. 26 by mistake but after then i have edited my comment. just insert line in manifest where error redirects to you.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani the thing is that I cannot click the error that can redirect me into some manifest file, I have my manifest file showed on post, can u point out which line I should add that ?

Comment: I am not sure about this but i have faced same problem and i added this line in manifest somewhere and it solved my problem. So, i have suggested this solution to you. Try adding this line in `<application>` tag and it doesn't work then try adding line into `manifest` tag. e.g. `<application tools:replace="android:value"...>`

Comment: I get Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs after the change you mentioned!

Comment: Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:44 for attribute android:value, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 43 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: Can i know before you get the first manifest merger error which lines you have added into manifest? I think you have added any meta-tag in your manifest and that creates this problem. So, please let me know which line of code you have added before getting this error.

Comment: there is no problem with manifest unless I add this line: compile project(':react-native-onesignal') into app.build.gradle within dependencies

Comment: Is it (react-native-onesignal) module in your project?

Comment: yes it is, well for me it sounds more like version conflicts between one signal and google support lib

Comment: fixed it, it was versioning issue between google support google services

Comment: thnx for trying to help and the time!

Comment: glad to hear that. please let me know the solution so i can use it in future.

Comment: i answerd it...

Answer (score 1):

This code solved my problem

```
   configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
          if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.1.0'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```